# Install Headless Chrome in Suse

Tags: chrome, suse, zypper

I am trying to install a headless Chrome browser. My current OS is **SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)**.

I am following this guide: https://www.simplified.guide/google-chrome/install-on-suse

But it fails with this error:

```
# sudo zypper install --no-confirm google-chrome-stable
Refreshing service 'SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server_12_SP1_x86_64'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

What am I missing? How can I get the `libvulkan.so.1()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the argument `--no-confirm` from the command, you can choose between the two options:

`Solution 1: do not install google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64`

`Solution 2: break google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies`

Choosing the solution 2, the installation proceeds and you'll be able to use Chrome.